# music play back via USB connected to karaoke player

Tags: usb-host-mode

I am trying to play music on my Nexus7 via USB  connected to a karaoke player. It does not play through karaoke player speakers. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of android do you have? If its jellybean or later then it doesnt support this because if you plug it into your jukebox, it doesnt recognises it due to it being in 'Media Device' mode not the old USB memory mode so if you cant find `Settings>Storage>(The little three dots in the top right corner)USB computer connection>MTP device` if you can find this option, tick it, if not then you could try another method eg. Transferring to USB stick/Plugging in speakers into the 'Headphone' slot on your android
Please tick this answer if it solves your problem

Comment: If I root the phone can I listen music worth usb output